# Why is this JavaScript code not working in document ready, but does when I wrap it inside script type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following function in JavaScript:

```
function valueChanged(){
   if (jQuery('#home_room_type_kitchen').is(":checked")) {
      console.log('shown');jQuery('#product_section_one').show();
   } else {
      console.log('hiden');jQuery('#product_section_one').hide();
   }
}

valueChanged();
```

when I put this inside an existing `jQuery(document).ready(function(){});` .js file declaration, the script does not run and returns `Uncaught ReferenceError: valueChanged is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange`.

Yet when I put this inside the html file and wrap it inside `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`, the code runs fine.

I am really confused why this is the case, and what I am missing here. I thought putting this function inside a document ready .js file would work fine?

Comment: Well it is because of scope..... put it inside a document ready, it is not global any more. You should probably bind the event with jQuery instead of using inline event handlers.

Comment: yes you are totally correct re:binding event. or would you recommend event listener for this if i have to determine multiple radio checks on a long form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function declaration should be outside of the ready function separately defined, then just call it inside the ready fuction, like  :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        valueChanged();
    });

    function valueChanged(){
      if (jQuery('#home_room_type_kitchen').is(":checked")) {
        console.log('shown');jQuery('#product_section_one').show();
      } else {
        console.log('hiden');jQuery('#product_section_one').hide();
      }
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ah yes; of course. duh. you rock. hope this helps someone in future.